# Improving the readibility of bright text on a bright background

Tags: css

I' im interested in improving the readibility of a bright text on a background which is partially bright.

I think the readibility would improve if one could create a dark border around the text. Is that possible in WordPress?

Or does somebody of you have another proposal how to solve this problem?

The site I' m referring to:

[www.sabertec.net](http://www.sabertec.net)

Readability problems especially on:

[www.sabertec.net/news/](http://sabertec.net/news/)

Greetings,
Peter123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of increasing the contrast for the letters is to add a drop shadow to them. Use `text-shadow` in CSS for that:

```
.entry-content p {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000;
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot, thank you again! One last problem remains: the headings are not affected by this. There is no shadow attached to them.

Comment: I just put `.entry-content p` as selector to only affect paragraphs of the post content. It depends on what else you want to have affected, you can use `main` or `article` instead. The choice of selector is up to you.